# Actionscript 3 getDefinitionByName not seeing classes

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I've worked around this with a hack for now, but would rather know if there's a right way to do it. I have a function that churns out MovieClips, which are tiles for a map that I then attach to the stage. It determines which class of tile to use based on a string variable, like this:

```
// symbolID holds our class name, determined by logic above
var newClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(symbolID) as Class;
var newtile:MovieClip = new newClass();
```

This works, but *only* if an instance of the class already exists somewhere else in the code. It could be anywhere-- in the document class, in some buried function of a helper class, it doesn't seem to matter. If not, Flashdevelop throws error 1065, "Variable (the variable) is not defined". I mention that I'm using Flashdevelop because it seems like it might be compiler-specific, but I'm not sure.

My hack fix is to do this:

```
var a:baseTile;
a as anotherTile;
a as aThirdTile;
```

and so on, which works, but definitely isn't ideal if I'm going to have hundreds of these tile classes eventually.

Edit: I should add that these movieclips are coming from a .swc file, which comes from Flash Professional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the 'hack'.

`getDefinitionByName()` can only work with classes that exist at runtime. Unfortunately, if you don't make use of a class, it won't be compiled and won't exist at runtime.

Library symbols make getting around this a little easier. If you check the box that has them available automatically at a given frame, you can just make sure your `getDefinitionByName()` calls are done during or after that frame.

[image]

Comment: Ah HA. So that's why it felt like a compiler issue. Thanks very much. I will try the "Export in frame 1" option. I'm not sure it will work, since as a pure Actionscript project, the entire thing takes place in frame 1. If not, I will just have to make a linkage library like suggested below (which was what I was basically doing with my fix even though I didn't realize it).

Answer (score 1):

While SWC libraries can include specific classes to include in the build path, Flash compiler will not link unreferenced classes to a SWF; therefore, requires a linkage library.

Example linkage to retain classes:

```
/** linkage library */
private static const classA:ClassA;
private static const classB:ClassB;
private static const classC:ClassC;
```

Another option would be to load the classes from a [RSL (Runtime Shared Library)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf674ba-7fff.html).

Comment: I like a Class array better. `private static const dummy:Array=[ClassA, ClassB, ClassC];`

Answer (score 1):

Basically yes, you need to have a strict reference of that class somewhere in your code. You can even make that reference "unreferenced" elsewhere. I have a hundred of classes like this, and I had to make a single `Array` of these classes, located somewhere inside the project. I have placed it aside the function that calls `getDefinitionByName()` to make sure the classes are available in that function.

```
private static const dummy:Array=[Rock01, Rock02,...,Gem01,Gem02,...];
```

So you can use such an Array listing all your tiles that you have in your project and want to be accessible by `getDefinitionByName()`.